# nolock hint is not working when update inside transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table named Users is updated inside a transaction alongside other batches, When procedure is in progress Users table is locked and i cant select from it even if i use `nolock` hint

```
BEGIN TRY 
BEGIN TRANSACTION
---------------------------Apply Users Changes-----------------------------


      ALTER TABLE Security.Users NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;


   ...Other batches

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @usersCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #xyz),
            @batchCount INT = 20,
            @batchesDone INT = 0
    WHILE @batchesDone * @batchCount < @usersCount
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Users
        SET [UserName] = ISNULL(a.UserName,a.Code),
            [Code] = ISNULL(a.[Code], '0'),
            [Password] = ISNULL([Password], dbo.HashPassword(ISNULL(a.[Code], '0'))),
            [Mobile] = a.[Mobile],
        FROM (
            SELECT * FROM #xyz
            WHERE RN > @batchesDone * @batchCount AND RN <= (@batchesDone + 1) * @batchCount
        ) a
        WHERE Users.Username = a.UserName
    
        SET @batchesDone += 1
    END
    END 


          
    ALTER TABLE Security.Users CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    RAISERROR(@message,16,1)
    END CATCH
```

If i use nolock it will be hanging until procedure execution is finished

```
SELECT * FROM Users (NOLOCK)
WHERE LDAPUsername='aaa'
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `NOLOCK` in the first place? You do understand the consequences of uses the hint are, correct? Using it against a table your performing an `UPDATE` against is a recipe of disaster.

Comment: then what should i do? my entire application stop working when procedure is running

Comment: Getting rid of the `WHILE` would be a start, or at least increasing the batch size; a well designed database can handle millions of rows in a matter of seconds or less. Handling all those rows in batches of just 20 will be terrible for performance.

Comment: Surely the whole point of batching that update statement is so that you can commit between each batch. I would suggest that disabling your check constraints is a bad idea and not giving you any improvements (unless they are super complex regex).

Comment: [Stop splattering your code with nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you must and you understand the consequences and you accept that your code will not always work correctly, then AT LEAST use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax. EVOLVE!

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
ALTER TABLE Security.Users NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Without commmitting it requires SQL Server to take out a Schema Share lock on the table, this means that another session is unable to even generate a query plan. The `nolock` hint cannot be used to ignore these.

You can see this for yourself by running

```
begin transaction 
ALTER TABLE Security.Users NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Then in another session do any query against `security.users`, and in another check what's going on using Adam Machanic's `sp_whoisactive` procedure (http://whoisactive.com/). You'd see that the query session is waiting on `LCK_M_SCH_S` which you can google around.

As explained in my comment earlier, it is very unlikely that disabling your check constraints is actually benefitting you at all, I suggest you don't do it. If you do want to then just call it outside your explicit transaction so it commits straightaway (and allows everyone else to modify the data in anyway they please).

Obligatory warning that `nolock` can and will give you logically inconsistent data when you are modifying the data that is being looked at.

Comment: what if it bumps to exception? should i use ALTER TABLE Security.Users CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL inside catch block?

Comment: Have you actually made sure it's helping you? If you are going to do it (and allow other sessions to ignore your check constraints) then do it completely outside your try catch blocks. There is no `finally` for T-SQL (weirdly) so you'll just have to stick it outside